# Constructor Parameter based on a Delegate

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a case where I need Unity to capture constructor values during "resolve" instead of during registration.  Notice this extension:

```
public class DataAccessRegistry : UnityContainerExtension, IDataAccessConfig
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static string connection = "";

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<DataAccess>(
           new InjectionProperty("log"),  
           new InjectionConstructor(connection));
    }

    public IDataAccessConfig WithConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        connection = connectionString;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This sample code doesn't work correctly because `InjectionConstructor(connection)` is taking a snapshot of what the `connection` variable contained during registration.  Instead I need each executing thread to have the opportunity to change the `connection` variable, through the `WithConnection` method, and have the subsequent resolved DataAccess instance properly contain the current `connection` value.

Somehow a delegate needs to be thrown into the mix to make this work.  So I tried changing the `RegisterType<DataAccess>()` to look like this:

```
        Container.RegisterType<DataAccess>(
            new InjectionProperty("log"),  //custom BuildStrategy again.
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
            {
                var dao = new DataAccess(connection);
                c.BuildUp(dao);   //Try to make custom BuildStrategy apply.
                return dao;
            }));
```

The delegate did its job and fixed the problem, but now the `InjectionProperty("log")` doesn't work because it is being ignored.  When Unity sees the `InjectionFactory`, it ignores the `InjectionProperty`.

So now I'm thinking the solution is to have a custom `InjectionParameter` that takes a delegate.  But I want to know if there is another way to do this without such customization.

I'm using Unity 2.1, but could upgrade if it would help solve this problem.  I'm also curious how this would be solved with other .net IOC containers...

p.s. In my case the "log" property is being handled with a [logger custom BuildStrategy](http://blog.baltrinic.com/software-development/dotnet/log4net-integration-with-unity-ioc-container), but that is just trivia - not relevant for answering this question.